# how to parse two xml tags in the same level using a for-each method using xslt?

Tags: xslt

I am converting a xml using xslt.

Original XML is

```
<Content>
  <book>
     <customData>
          <CustomDataElement>
             <title>book-name</title>
             <value>Java</value>
          </CustomDataElement>
          <CustomDataElement>
             <title>genre</title>
             <value>Programming</value>
          </CustomDataElement>
     </customData>
  </book>
  <authors>
    <author>
       <name>authorOne</name>
       <country>US</country>
    </author>
  </authors>
  <book>
     <customData>
          <CustomDataElement>
             <title>book-name</title>
             <value>Stranger</value>
          </CustomDataElement>
          <CustomDataElement>
             <title>genre</title>
             <value>Fiction</value>
          </CustomDataElement>
     </customData>
  </book>
  <authors>
    <author>
       <name>authorthree</name>
       <country>UK</country>
    </author>
  </authors>
</Content>
```

and my xslt is as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Content/book">
<media>
    <book>
<xsl:apply-templates select="customData/CustomDataElement[title = 'book-name']" />
    </book>

    <genre>
<xsl:apply-templates select="customData/CustomDataElement[title = 'genre']" />
    </genre>
    <author>
    <xsl:value-of select="../authors/author/name" />
    </author>
</media>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CustomDataElement">
<xsl:value-of select="value" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me output as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<media>
   <book>Java</book>
   <genre>Programming</genre>
   <author>authorOne</author>
</media>
<media>
   <book>Stranger</book>
   <genre>Fiction</genre>
   <author>authorOne</author>
</media>
```

I want the authors name from the tag 'authors\author' which follows the book tag.

what i am missing here ? pls help

Comment: yes...i am using for-each for "content/book"..but in the output, i need author tag as a subtag of book which is not a case in input...whatever i tried is giving me always first book's author...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="../authors/author/name" />
```

try

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::authors[1]/author/name" />
```

Since you are in the context of a `book` node, this xpath says to look for the first (`[1]`) following sibling `authors` node, and to select the `author/name` from that.

Comment: perfect...thanks....
just one more question .....where do i find this documentation of 
'following-sibling' and other like same....

Comment: @Vijay it's in MSDN, I often refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx and you can see the documentation tree around that article.